# Build app flutter "flutter build apk --flavor staging --release"

Tags: flutter

I can build flutter app by command-line "flutter build apk --flavor stg --release" but i through erorr "Keystore file not set for signing config release".

Answer (score 0):

Follow the document about release flutter app https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android

On Mac/Linux, use the following command:

```
  keytool -genkey -v -keystore ~/upload-keystore.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias upload
```

On Windows, use the following command:

```
  keytool -genkey -v -keystore c:\Users\USER_NAME\upload-keystore.jks -storetype JKS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias upload
```

In Run/Debug Configurations

In line "Additionl run args:" type "--debug"
In line "Build flavor" type "staging"

And Run command: `flutter build apk —release --flavor staging`

[This is example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMmmL.png)

Comment: build success but it crash when installed apk !@@

Comment: Can you please send me crash log when start app. Try install different devices,